# connecting arduino output with python read in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I am currently running a project as a designer so needless to say the programming is not my most evolved skill.
I have an arduino with it connected a flowsensor, and i want an python program to react on the serial monitor print. In the beginning now i just want the python code to print a text "resived input" to reconice that this connection work.

Currently i am running Arduino from VS code succesfully and i print to serial monitor reading from COM3.
When running the python program nothing shows in the terminal and i get the following message.

```
C:/Users/roenn/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/roenn/Downloads/chrome-dinosaur-master/chrome-dinosaur-master/import_serial.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\roenn\Downloads\chrome-dinosaur-master\chrome-dinosaur-master\import_serial.py", line 4, in <module>
    arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)  # Replace 'COM3' with the port where your Arduino is connected
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\roenn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 33, in __init__
    super(Serial, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\roenn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "C:\Users\roenn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 64, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)
```

I am a little confused and hoped you could help.

I have the following arduino code.

```
int flowPin = 2;    // This is the input pin on the Arduino
double flowRate;    // This is the value we intend to calculate.
volatile int count; // This integer needs to be set as volatile to ensure it updates correctly during the interrupt process.

void Flow()
{
  count++; // Every time this function is called, increment "count" by 1
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(flowPin, INPUT);           // Sets the pin as an input
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(flowPin), Flow, RISING);  // Configures interrupt to run the function "Flow"
  Serial.begin(9600);               // Start Serial
}

void loop() {
  count = 0;        // Reset the counter so we start counting from 0 again
  interrupts();     // Enables interrupts on the Arduino
  delay(1000);      // Wait 1 second
  noInterrupts();   // Disable the interrupts on the Arduino

  // Start the math
  flowRate = (count * 2.25);        // Take counted pulses in the last second and multiply by 2.25mL
  flowRate = flowRate * 60;         // Convert seconds to minutes, giving you mL / Minute
  flowRate = flowRate / 1000;       // Convert mL to Liters, giving you Liters / Minute

  //Serial.println(flowRate);         // Print the variable flowRate to Serial
 
   if(flowRate > 0) {
    Serial.println("1");
  } 
 
  delay(1000); // for connecting with python
  Serial.flush(); // For connecting with python
}
```

And my python code is the following.

```
import serial

# Create a serial object
arduino = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)  # Replace 'COM3' with the port where your Arduino is connected

while True:
    data = arduino.readline()  # Read the data sent from the Arduino
    if data:
        print("Received data: ", data)
```

In my folder i am also running the crome dinasaur game as a pygame. in the end i want the dinasaur to jump when the flowsensor senses flow. But for know i just want python to react to the serial output. I was of the belive that runnign both python and arduino in VS code would enable the same program to read from the same port but i might be wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the Serial in the Arduino IDE app before trying to open it in python, It can not be opened at two locations at the same time.